# Doctrine "reverse" orphan removal

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have two entities (simplified):

```
class EncryptedMasterKey {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ExchangeFile", inversedBy="encryptedMasterKeys")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="exchange_file_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     * @var ExchangeFile
     */
    protected $exchangeFile;
}
```

and

```
class ExchangeFile {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EncryptedMasterKey", mappedBy="exchangeFile", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $encryptedMasterKeys;
}
```

There can be many `EncryptedMasterKey`s for one `ExchangeFile` in the database. If the `ExchangeFile` is deleted, all related encrypted `MasterKeys` are deleted (`orphanRemoval=true` and `cascade={"persist", "remove"}` make sure this is the case). So far, so good.

Now as the actual file lies encrypted on the hard disk, there must be **at least one `EncryptedMasterKey`** so that the file can be decrypted. So when a `EncryptedMasterKey` is deleted and I discover that it is the last one for it's `ExchangeFile`, I also have to delete the `ExchangeFile` **because it cannot be decrypted any more**. An `ExchangeFile` cannot live without at least one `EncryptedMasterKey`.

How do I achieve this? `@ORM\PreRemove` in the `EncryptedMasterKey` class does't really help me because I don't have access to the Entity Manager:

```
class EncryptedMasterKey {
    //...
    /** @ORM\PreRemove */
    public function removeOrphanExchangeFile()
    {
        if ($this->exchangeFile->isTheOnlyMasterKey($this))
            // I don't have access to the Entity Manager,
            // so how do I delete the ExchangeFile?
    }
}
```

Is there any elegant solution to this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [event subscriber](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#the-event-system) and create a class like following:

```
class MyEncryptedMasterSubscriber implements \Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(\Doctrine\ORM\Events::onFlush);
    }

    public function onFlush(\Doctrine\ORM\Events\OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $uow = $eventArgs->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork();


        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityDeletions() AS $entity) {
            if (
                $entity instanceof EncryptedMasterKey 
                && $entity->getExchangeFile()->isTheOnlyMasterKey($entity)
            ) {
                $uow->scheduleForDelete($entity->getExchangeFile());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about how to register subscribers in the particular case of Symfony 2 on [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) for it.

Comment: That's the way to go. Thanks a lot Ocramius!

Comment: There seems to be one particular problem with this solution: If I try to access the encrypted master keys collection (`$this->getEncrpytedMasterKeys()` inside `ExchangeFile`), the collection (`PersistentCollection`) is not initialized any more. Therefore, there seems to be no `EncryptedMasterKey` for that `ExchangeFile` (although in reality there is). Before that event, the collection is initialized. Why are persistent collections not initialized any more when I'm in an `onFlush` event?

Comment: @to0om persistent collections are initialized only once. Did you verify if it wasn't already initialized?

Comment: It hasn't been initialized yet, because `$exchangeFile->getEncryptedMasterKeys()` hasn't been called until the listener is executed (in that particular case). In any other case, when I call `$exchangeFile->getEncryptedMasterKeys()`, `getIterator()` and therefore `initialize()` is called within the `PersistentCollection`. I just can't explain why it doesn't work in this case.